# How to access Gatsby Create Page template GraphQL variable inside JSX?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

How can I access and use `$category` within `<div>` as `<h2>$category</h2>` ?

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
export default ({ data }) => {
  const posts = data.posts
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <h1>List of Posts</h1>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
export const query = graphql`
  query($category: String!) {
    posts( { category: { name: $category} }) {
      summary
    }
  }
`
```

Please note that GraphQL returns a list of objects (instead of one object) in my case. I can read it from first item in the list but wondering if there is any better way. Also in some cases, list could be empty, so that'll not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `category` from the property `pageContext` as shown here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#pass-context-to-pages

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can't use variables inside GraphQL queries. The problem is that these GraphQL queries are extracted during the Gatsby build process **before** any variables are instantiated. See this [github issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/14642#issuecomment-505366854):

> There is no other way to pass variables, pages are created at
>   gatsby-node level. Your only option is inline variables like I
>   described above, either in page query or in useStaticQuery. We have
>   plans to make useQuery accept variables, but there is no ETA.